# Как сохранить результат метода при перевороте экрана (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой (практикуюсь по книге Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 3-е издание - застрял на последних заданиях 5-й главы):
    ниже класс, который позволяет пользователю подсмотреть правильный ответ на простой вопрос. После просмотра подсказки при переходе обратно к вопросам и нажав на правильный ответ пользователь увидит надпись "Читерить нехорошо". Проблема в том, что в данном классе нужно сохранить результат - подсмотрел ли пользователь ответ, чтобы при перевороте экрана телефона этот показатель не обнулился. Я не пойму как это осуществить. Что конкретно нужно сохранить? В места кода -> (________)  я пробовал подставить значение mAnswerIsTrue - но это не дало ожидаемых результатов. Я думаю что нужно сохранить результат выполнения метода wasAnswerShown, но это лишь предположение.
Заранее спасибо)

```
 public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //константа TAG (источник сообщения) = "имя класса"
    public  static final String TAG = "CheatActivity";

    //ключ для дополнения-интента который CheatActivity читает и использует (в методе newIntent)
    private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
    //ключ дополнения для назначения результата
    private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_shown";

    private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;

    private TextView mAnswerTextView;
    private Button mShowAnswerButton;

    //инкапсулированный метод для включения дополнения в интент
    //он позволяет создать объект Intent, настроенный дополнениями, необходимыми для CheatActivity
    // boolean answerIsTrue - выступает значением в дополнении
    // (включение дополнения в интент - интент.дополнение(ключ,значение))
    public static Intent newIntent (Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue){
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
        //далее интент.дополнение (ключ, значение)
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
        return intent;
    }

    //декодирование интента результата (из метода setAnswerShownResult)
    public static boolean wasAnswerShown (Intent result){
        return result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");// <- эта строка регистрирует сообщение (Log.d),
        // ^(источник сообщения,"какое сообщение вывести")
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
           ___________ = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, ___________);
        }

        // метод для чтения значения из дополнения + сохранение значения в переменной mAnswerIsTrue
        mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

        mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);
        mShowAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
        //далее когда нажимаем на "Show Answer" - показать текст правильного ответа
        mShowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                }
                    else {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                }
                setAnswerShownResult(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAnswerShownResult (boolean isAnswerShown) {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    }


@Override 
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        saveInstanceState.putBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN,__________);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Для начала нужно объявить переменную `private boolean mWasAnswerShown`

2) В методе onCreate нужно доставать сохранённое значение таким образом:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   mWasAnswerShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false); 
   // второй параметр - значение по умолчанию
   // если в savedInstanceState не окажется объекта с тегом EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN
}
```

3) А в методе onSaveInstanceState сохранять значение переменной mWasAnswerShown таким образом:

```
saveInstanceState.putBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, mWasAnswerShown);
```

---

P.S. если вы запускаете активити CheatActivity из той активити с вопросами и вам нужны некие результаты работы CheatActivity, то так же можно использовать в вашей активити с вопросами старт CheatActivity с ожиданием результатов:

```
Intent startCheatActivityIntent = new Intent(this, CheatActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(startCheatActivityIntent, 1);
```

В коде CheatActivity положить нужные данные в интент:

```
Intent resultsIntent = new Intent();
resultsIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, mWasAnswerShown);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultsIntent);
finish();
```

При возврате из CheatActivity в коде активити с вопросами вы будете иметь доступ к этому интенту, в который положили данные, в следующем методе:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (data == null)
      return;
   boolean wasAnswerShown = data.getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN);
   if(wasAnswerShown)
      Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, "Читерить нехорошо", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Супер, это то что нужно! Спасибо) Немного запутаннее чем я думал.

Comment: Прошу Вас, немного разъясните, значение объявленной переменной mWasAnswerShown находиться через ключ EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN - верно? В целом, для чего нужны такие ключи?

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов, для идентификации объектов. Так как, например в вашем случае, в `Intent` вы можете положить два значения типа boolean `mAnswerIsTrue` и `mWasAnswerShown`, поэтому для каждой переменной нужно иметь такой тег. Обычно их объявляют как `public static final` в каком-нибудь одном месте

Comment: То есть, для упомянутых переменных mAnswerIsTrue и mWasAnswerShown должны быть разные ключи, иначе будут конфликты, и если я в методе onSaveInstanceState укажу ключ необходимой переменной то ее значение будет сохранено - верно?

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов, да, для каждого объекта - свой ключ, так как в Bundle всё хранится в виде пар "ключ - значение". Соответственно под каким ключом вы сохраните, под таким и следует вытаскивать обратно

Comment: Благодарю, Вы здорово помогли мне)

Answer (score 0):

При повороте экрана заново вызывается метод onCreate. Мне кажется, что ты можешь переопределить методы onStop или onPause и в них сохранить состояния. А в методе onCreate посмотреть, не пусто ли сохранённое состояние и если нет, вытащить его.